# Error: Entrypoint doesn't contain a main function Flutter

Tags: flutter

I got an error Error: Entrypoint doesn't contain a main function Flutter, I tried to restart android studio but it did not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me:

When new project is created then got the error `"Entrypoint doesn't contain a main function Flutter"`.

To resolve this I followed below step

First make sure your **flutter** and **dart** sdk paths are properly configured.

You can **re-include the files/project root** folder.
Goto File -> Project Structure -> Module

And then add the root folder of the project by clicking + icon, then it will detect a flutter app again.

Build the project and check for the error.

Answer (score 10):

Depends on what the program is support to do. There should be a main class that is initiated. As an example:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:english_words/english_words.dart';
    void main() => runApp(MyApp()); // initiate MyApp as  StatelessWidget

    // Main class
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      // creating main screen and building list of wordpairs
      @override
```

Answer (score 1):

add main function to your project. you might miss that
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use same name of project and pubspec.yaml file name Sometime it happens when we copy one pubspec file for another project.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30161473)

Answer (score 1):

There's another case where this is possible, because of dart package file

delete all that `.packages` files, should get resolved.

Comment: You are right, in my case I renamed the project name from projectA to proj. It caused the issue and I deleted .dart_toosl folder & pubspec.lock file then restarted the IDE. Solved

Answer (score 1):

run "flutter clean" and then "flutter pub get" and then try again if that did not do the trick you can always use the "flutter run" command to run your project

Answer (score 0):

Just do this

> File -> Project structure -> Modules

From right select

> Sources

form [Source, Paths, Dependencies] Tabs

Select Plus Icon -> Apply -> ok button

Answer (score 0):

in my case the launching function was named something else, renamed it to main, then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Add this if its missing in your main.dart file
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

This function tells Dart where the program starts, and it must be in the file that is considered the "entry point" for you program.

Answer (score -1):

I cut some text above the main function and that included a closing } which made the main inside some class above it. That caused the above error. I put back the } above main and everything became ok.