# Flutter Xcode "Undefined name 'main'."

Tags: xcode, flutter, build

When i try to build my flutter project in xcode or via "flutter build ios" command i get this error:

[image: Xcode screenshot]

This is the flutter doctor output:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on macOS 12.2 21D49 darwin-arm, locale it-IT)
    • Flutter version 2.8.1 at /Users/Fenix/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 77d935af4d (7 settimane fa), 2021-12-16 08:37:33 -0800
    • Engine revision 890a5fca2e
    • Dart version 2.15.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
    • Android SDK at /Users/Fenix/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 32.1.0-rc1
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio M1.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7772763)

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.63.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension can be installed from:
       https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
```

I tried with checking "For install builds only" in Build Phases but i get different error of files not found.
I also tried with flutter clean, Clean Build Folder, pod reinstall, etc.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried by clearing derived data first ? then flutter clean , flutter pub get  and pod install

Comment: Do you have any flavor of your app?

Comment: @HardikMehta yes i tried

Comment: @Fahmida nope, my app is basically standard

Comment: @EdoardoCortese : Please check this   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59636587/error-entrypoint-doesnt-contain-a-main-function-flutter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved by using this command to build:

```
flutter build ios -t lib/splashscreen.dart --release
```

Where splashscreen.dart is the entrypoint for your app, where `void main() => runApp(...)` is placed.

Thanks for all comments.

Answer (score 0):

you have forgotten in your code to add void main => runapp(/your class which contains materialapp()/)